# Stylus imports styl files from the wrong folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, stylus

I have a file `mobile.styl` that collects all styl files I need via `@import`:

```
@import '../../common/styles/colors'
@import '../../common/styles/init'


@import 'landing'
@import 'faq'
@import 'vehicle'
```

I have two `'landing'` styl files, one is in current folder where `mobile.styl` is and another is  where those two first imported files are `../../common/styles/`.

If I have the order of imports like shown above, then stylus imports first `colors` and `init` files which is fine, but then it loads `landing` file NOT from current folder where `mobile.styl` is, but from `../../common/styles/` so I get the wrong styl file, which is for desktop version.

Now, if I put those two imports to the end of the file, then it first loads `landing`, `faq`, `vehicle` properly, then those two files from the proper paths as expected.

Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've dealt with this same issue. A few solutions I've found are:

- Rename one of the files to something unique.

  - change `landing.styl` to `landing-mobile.styl`
- Move the file you want to import into it's own folder

  - move `landing.styl` to `mobile/landing.styl`
- Import a file from the folder root you want to be in before importing the file of the same name

  - import `empty.styl` that lives next to `landing.styl` then import `landing.styl`
- Lastly, you can reference the path relative to the last file imported

  - import `../../landing.styl`

I've placed the options in order of my personal preference, but they all should do the trick.

Comment: Good to know it's not some mysterious unreproducible bug but more like just a rare case which is not covered in Stylus code.